Prop table in R with grouping factor and likert scale answers columns
I have a data set with Likert scale answers. I want to create a new data frame that will calculate the percentages of each category of each level. Doing so i have made the following code:

likert_levels <- c(
  "Very Dissatisfied",
  "Dissatisfied",
  "Average",
  "Satisfied",
  "Very Satisfied"
)

df <-
  tibble(
    "q1" = sample(likert_levels, 10, replace = TRUE),
    "q2" = sample(likert_levels, 10, replace = TRUE, prob = 5:1),
    "q3" = sample(likert_levels, 10, replace = TRUE, prob = 1:5),
    "q4" = sample(likert_levels, 10, replace = TRUE, prob = 1:5),
    "q5" = sample(c(likert_levels, NA), 10, replace = TRUE)
  ) %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ factor(.x, levels = likert_levels)))%>%
  mutate(Country = c("USA","BRAZIL","BRAZIL","BRAZIL","USA","GERMANY","ITALY","GERMANY","BRAZIL","USA"))%>%
  relocate(Country,.before=q1)


df$O_1 <- apply(df, 1, function(x) sum(x=="Very Dissatisfied", na.rm=TRUE)) #How many ONEstars in                                    
df$O_2 <- apply(df, 1, function(x) sum(x=="Dissatisfied", na.rm=TRUE)) #each row
df$O_3 <- apply(df, 1, function(x) sum(x=="Average", na.rm=TRUE))
df$O_4 <- apply(df, 1, function(x) sum(x=="Satisfied", na.rm=TRUE))
df$O_5 <- apply(df, 1, function(x) sum(x=="Very Satisfied", na.rm=TRUE))

df$O_sum <-  df$O_1 + df$O_2 + df$O_3 + df$O_4 + df$O_5
df <- df[,-c(2: (ncol(df)-6))]



Likert_df =  as.data.frame (df %>% group_by(Country,O_sum) %>% summarise( 
  OO_1 = sum(O_1) / (n() * (O_sum[1])) * 100,
  OO_2 = sum(O_2) / (n() * (O_sum[1])) * 100,
  OO_3 = sum(O_3) / (n() * (O_sum[1])) * 100,
  OO_4 = sum(O_4) / (n() * (O_sum[1])) * 100,
  OO_5 = sum(O_5) / (n() * (O_sum[1])) * 100 ) ) 

Likert_df$ O_sum <- NULL

Likert_df <- as.data.frame(Likert_df %>% group_by(Country) %>% summarise(
  
  OO_1 = mean(OO_1),
  OO_2 = mean(OO_2),
  OO_3 = mean(OO_3),
  OO_4 = mean(OO_4),
  OO_5 = mean(OO_5) ))


colnames(Likert_df) <- c("Item",  "Strongly Disagree",  "Disagree",  "So So",  "Agree",  "Strongly Agree")
DF = Likert_df

resulting to :
DF
     Item Strongly Disagree Disagree So So Agree Strongly Agree
1  BRAZIL                10       25  25.0  30.0             10
2 GERMANY                30       20  20.0  20.0             10
3   ITALY                20       40  20.0   0.0             20
4     USA                 5       10  42.5  17.5             25

My question is: Is there another way more simpler and faster using dplyr functions with pipes to create the same result ?

Use proportions(), prop.table is an earlier name, retained for back-compatibility, check ?proportions.

@jay.sf how you can handle NAs ?

You could apply `==`() on the Likert levels on every slice you get using by() and proportions from that. No problems with NA's.
> by(df[-1], df$Country,\(x) 
+    proportions(colSums(sapply(likert_levels, \(z) x == z), na.rm=TRUE))) |> 
+   do.call(what='rbind')
        Very Dissatisfied Dissatisfied    Average Satisfied Very Satisfied
BRAZIL          0.2105263    0.2105263 0.00000000 0.2105263      0.3684211
GERMANY         0.1000000    0.4000000 0.10000000 0.4000000      0.0000000
ITALY           0.0000000    0.2000000 0.20000000 0.4000000      0.2000000
USA             0.1333333    0.3333333 0.06666667 0.2000000      0.2666667

If you rely on a Country column rather than row names, you could do
> unique(df[1]) |> cbind(
+   by(df, ~Country,\(x) 
+      proportions(colSums(sapply(likert_levels, \(z) x[-1] == z), na.rm=TRUE))) |> 
+     do.call(what='rbind')
+ )
  Country Very Dissatisfied Dissatisfied    Average Satisfied Very Satisfied
1     USA         0.2105263    0.2105263 0.00000000 0.2105263      0.3684211
2  BRAZIL         0.1000000    0.4000000 0.10000000 0.4000000      0.0000000
6 GERMANY         0.0000000    0.2000000 0.20000000 0.4000000      0.2000000
7   ITALY         0.1333333    0.3333333 0.06666667 0.2000000      0.2666667

Should be fast.

Data:
> dput(df)
structure(list(Country = c("USA", "BRAZIL", "BRAZIL", "BRAZIL", 
"USA", "GERMANY", "ITALY", "GERMANY", "BRAZIL", "USA"), q1 = structure(c(1L, 
5L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L), levels = c("Very Dissatisfied", 
"Dissatisfied", "Average", "Satisfied", "Very Satisfied"), class = "factor"), 
    q2 = structure(c(2L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 5L), levels = c("Very Dissatisfied", 
    "Dissatisfied", "Average", "Satisfied", "Very Satisfied"), class = "factor"), 
    q3 = structure(c(5L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L), levels = c("Very Dissatisfied", 
    "Dissatisfied", "Average", "Satisfied", "Very Satisfied"), class = "factor"), 
    q4 = structure(c(5L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 1L), levels = c("Very Dissatisfied", 
    "Dissatisfied", "Average", "Satisfied", "Very Satisfied"), class = "factor"), 
    q5 = structure(c(4L, 4L, NA, 2L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("Very Dissatisfied", 
    "Dissatisfied", "Average", "Satisfied", "Very Satisfied"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))

> dput(likert_levels)
c("Very Dissatisfied", "Dissatisfied", "Average", "Satisfied", 
"Very Satisfied")


I want to calculate the row wise sum not the column wise sum

@HomerJaySimpson The colSums calculate the sums of each Likert rating for every country that get in a matrix in an interim step.

one approach, starting from df:
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df |>
    pivot_longer(starts_with("q")) |>
    drop_na() |>
    count(Country, value) |>
    mutate(Perc = prop.table(n), .by = Country, value) |>
    pivot_wider(id_cols = Country, 
                names_from = value,
                values_from = Perc,
                values_fill = 0 ## replace NA with 0
                )

  Country `Very Dissatisfied` Dissatisfied Average Satisfied `Very Satisfied`
  <chr>                 <dbl>        <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>            <dbl>
1 BRAZIL                0.05         0.2     0.15      0.25            0.35  
2 GERMANY               0.111        0.222   0.444     0.222           0     
3 ITALY                 0.25         0       0.25      0               0.5   
4 USA                   0            0.267   0.2       0.467           0.0667 

(adjust colnames as before)

NAs must not be a column.In the sum are na.rm =TRUE.Are not replaced with zero.

what about splicing in a drop_na() before counting?

can you edit it ?

Another base r take with split, table and sweep.
new_df <- lapply(split(df, df$Country), \(x) table(unlist(x[,-1])))
new_df <- do.call(rbind, new_df)
new_df <- 100 * sweep(new_df, 1, rowSums(new_df), "/")
colnames(new_df) <- c("Strongly Disagree",  "Disagree",  "So So",  "Agree",  "Strongly Agree")

Output (rounded):
> round(new_df, 1)
        Strongly Disagree Disagree So So Agree Strongly Agree
BRAZIL               21.1     21.1   0.0  21.1           36.8
GERMANY              10.0     40.0  10.0  40.0            0.0
ITALY                 0.0     20.0  20.0  40.0           20.0
USA                  13.3     33.3   6.7  20.0           26.7



Toy data provided by @jay.sf:
df <- structure(list(
  Country = c("USA", "BRAZIL", "BRAZIL", "BRAZIL", "USA", "GERMANY", "ITALY", "GERMANY", "BRAZIL", "USA"), 
  
  q1 = structure(
    c(1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L), 
    levels = c("Very Dissatisfied", "Dissatisfied", "Average", "Satisfied", "Very Satisfied"), 
    class = "factor"), 
  
  q2 = structure(
    c(2L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 5L), 
    levels = c("Very Dissatisfied", "Dissatisfied", "Average", "Satisfied", "Very Satisfied"), 
    class = "factor"), 
  
  q3 = structure(
    c(5L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L), 
    levels = c("Very Dissatisfied", "Dissatisfied", "Average", "Satisfied", "Very Satisfied"), 
    class = "factor"), 
  
  q4 = structure(
    c(5L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 1L), 
    levels = c("Very Dissatisfied", "Dissatisfied", "Average", "Satisfied", "Very Satisfied"), 
    class = "factor"), 
  
  q5 = structure(
    c(4L, 4L, NA, 2L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 2L), 
    levels = c("Very Dissatisfied", "Dissatisfied", "Average", "Satisfied", "Very Satisfied"), 
    class = "factor")), 
  
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))

Created on 2024-05-20 with reprex v2.1.0
